# Prevent loading PHP pages into Joomla wrapper

Tags: php, joomla, external, wrapper

I'm owner of some web site with dozen of web pages. Pages were made by using PHP. Before some time I discovered that some guys by using Joomla CMS and wrapper menu option included starting (login page) there and on this way confused members and other visitors, especially because "window" of wrapper isn't enough big and some information on my page aren't visible. On this way visitors connect these pages with me and get bad feeling about whole my site. I contacted these guys but no answer, then I tried to solve it by using $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] super variable but I didn't get right and working solution for this problem. Someone experienced similar problem? Thanks.

EDIT - This is the code

```
    $HTTP_REFERRER=%SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']; 
    if ($HTTP_REFERRER) { 
    // check if the referrer is on your noentry list 
    // if so redirect it to another page 
        if ($HTTP_REFERRER == "www.mean.visitor.com") { 
            echo 'referer is' . $HTTP_REFERRER; 
            die; 
        } // shows the referrer and formats ur local harddrive echo "You came from $HTTP_REFERRER"; 
    } else { 
    //everything is OK 
    }
```

Comment: What did you try exactly? Can we see your code?

Comment: $HTTP_REFERRER=%SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
if ($HTTP_REFERRER)
{
// check if the referrer is on your noentry list
// if so redirect it to another page
  if ($HTTP_REFERRER == "www.mean.visitor.com") 
  {
  echo 'referer is' . $HTTP_REFERRER;
  die;
  }
  // shows the referrer and formats ur local harddrive
  echo "You came from $HTTP_REFERRER";
}
else
{
  //everything is OK
}

Comment: Edit you post and put the code inside it. For example %SERVER should be $_SERVER...but put your code in the post so that it's clearer.

Comment: sorry I tried to re-post but won't accept carriage return, it put all ijn one row :(

Answer (score 0):

from the code you posted the first problem i see it's on the first line:

```
$HTTP_REFERRER=%SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
```

should be

```
$HTTP_REFERRER=$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
```

Then in the second if you must insert the web addresses you want to block. so change

```
if ($HTTP_REFERRER == "www.mean.visitor.com")
```

with

```
if ($HTTP_REFERRER == "the address yo want to block")
```

And write `die()` instead of `die`.

has something changed?